# webpage temporarily down / not loading (due to too many connections?)

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, connection

I've been working on updating my page using javascript/jquery and have now run into a small problem. I'm using ajax to update a comment area on my page and every so often my page will stop loading altogether and i can't load any of the other pages on my domain. After a few hours or so I can access it again, so i was wondering if it could have something to do with how many connections are in use?  I've only had this problem since I added the javascript to my page, any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: It can be caused by too many things. Best go to your hosting provider and ask them for analysis, access logs and such. Also if it crashes for an *hour* it is probably best to go and change your hosting company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reasons behind this. I will name the two which comes to my mind right now

- Your server (Web, Database) might be getting overloaded with too many requests.
- The JavaScript might be using [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technique which involves many alive HTTP connections thus limiting your server resources while there are active clients.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try asking my hosting provider about it :)

Comment: @user1199434 Make sure you get enough RAM for the capabilities of your web site.